# Ftp client directory listing

Tags: ftp, ftp-client

I am using apache commons ftp client library with my android ftp client i am successfully logged in from a samsung galaxy mobile through my ftp client to drivehq ftp server but not able to get directory listing from server get an exception of connection refused and i used AndFtp client on same mobile and logged in i got directory listing. i do not what is the problem i am giving my code here i used for that purpose.

```
private static FTPClient ftpClient=new FTPClient();;
void login(String host,String username,String password,int port)
    {
        try 
        {
            ftpClient.connect(host);
            ftpClient.login(username, password);
            ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("MyData");
            ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public ArrayList<File> getDirectoryListing()
    {       
        ArrayList<File> list=new ArrayList<File>();
        FTPFile[] files = null;

        try
        {

            Log.d(ftpClient.printWorkingDirectory(), "is working directory");
            files=ftpClient.listFiles();
            Toast.makeText(null, files[0].getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            for(FTPFile f:files)
            {
                String s=f.getName();
                Log.d(s, "is file");
                File fs=new File(s);
                list.add(fs);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to get the directory listing, just connect your pc to internet and then go to prompt command, type ipconfig. it will list the IPV4 address.
use that address in host name with user id and password. 
You will get directory listing